# Webmethod and complex object type problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webmethod

I've got a webmethod in .NET that returns a List of objects.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(enableSession: true)] 
public static List<CourseItem> GetItems() { 
    return (new MTE()).GetItems(); 
}
```

And the CourseItem object as follows:

```
public static CourseItem {
    public string CourseNum { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

I consume the webmethod from javascript like thus:

```
function GetCourses_Success(result) {
    // Problem starts here
    if (result.d != null) {
        for (i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
            alert(result.d[i]["CourseNum"]);
}
```

**PROBLEM:**
The Alert sometimes says 'NaN' instead of the actual course number. The problem has to do with the fact that most of the course numbers are just numbers, but there is the occasional course number that is a number with an asterisk at the end of it (eg - 111234* or 999234*). So somewhere along the way between the webmethod and the alert something is trying to be too smart for its own good and thinking that CourseNum is a number field (integer perhaps) when in reality its just a string.

I also tried

```
result.d[i]["CourseNum"].toString()
```

but the alert still says 'NaN'

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: I'd be interested to know if it would work if you were to, say, assign the value to a label as opposed to alerting it; though, my money says it will still yield the same result.  You might also try a hacky approach: `var foo = result.d[i]["CourseNum"] + '';`

Comment: You're correct - it does yield the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the asterisk.  It's quite possible that Javascript believes you are multiplying.  As you aptly put it, something (Javascript) is too smart for its own good.